# How to get the sides of a triangle within a larger triangle?

Tags: geometry

I wasn't sure how to title this... this is my first time attempting to explain a general geometry problem, so please correct or edit my problem if it's ambiguous or comment if you need clarification. I'll try to explain it as well as I can.

Here is the problem:

Given a rectangle with sides $a$ and $b$ and diagonal $c$, with one inner horizontal and one inner vertical line where $a$ and $b$ are split in such a way that $d + e = a$ and $d > e$,  and $f + g = b$ and $f > g$, and $h + i = c$, and $h > i$. Now you have, among others, two triangles where $d^2 + f^2 = h^2$ and $e^2 + g^2 = i^2$. You are given $a$, $b$, $c$, and $h$. Find $e$ and $g$.

Is it possible to find $e$ and $g$ without knowing $d$ and $f$?

Edit: Here is a photo:

[image: Photo of problem]

Comment: Please draw a picture.

Comment: I added a photo of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knowing $a$, $b$ and $h$ tells you everything about the entire figure. Knowing $h$ tells you exactly where the intersection point in your figure is, which determines everything else.

To actually carry out the calculation, note that by similar triangles we have:

$$h/c=d/a=f/b$$

So $d=ah/c$ and $f=bh/c$.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is *yes*; moreover, you do not need to be given $c=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ separately.

What you need to use is similarity of the triangles:
$$ \frac{e}{i} = \frac{d}{h} = \frac{a}{c} $$
and
$$ \frac{g}{i} = \frac{f}{h} = \frac{b}{c} $$